# Why do functions in object properties disappear if stored in a session (meteor)?

Tags: javascript, session, meteor

Let's say I have an object

```
object = {
 property=function(){};
}
```

If I do `console.log(JSON.stringify(object))` it shows p`roperty=function(){}`, but if put the object in a session

```
Session.set("object", object");
console.log(JSON.stringify(Session.get("object"))
```

it doesn't show any properties.
Why does it happen, and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Session` is a Meteor Collection that implements the minimongo interface. It can only store documents (JSON) as properties, not functions, just as with MongoDB. For more information see http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection